# Automating Safari with Applescript: Intelligently switch to an already open tab based on URL

Tags: safari, applescript

I'm experimenting with automating my Mac with voice commands using the dictation feature. I've got the following simple script that will open up a new Safari tab with a url even if Safari is closed:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
end tell

set theUrl to "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"
tell application "Safari"
      if not (exists current tab of front window) then make new document -- if no window
      tell front window
        set current tab to (make new tab at end of tabs with properties {URL:theUrl})
      end tell
end tell
```

It works great. I can say "Mac, open Gmail" and it will pop open. I'd like to see if I can improve the script, though, and have the script determine if a site is already open in another tab and switch to that existing tab if it is. Is there a way to get the number of the first tab containing the URL I want?

Answer (score 2):

Sweet, thanks to the scripting genius at https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/safari-tabs.html I have a solution. I slightly modified the script there to achieve this. Here is the end result:

```
if application "Safari" is running then
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
    end tell
else
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        delay 5
    end tell
end if

set searchpat to "mail.google"
set theUrl to "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"

tell application "Safari"
    set winlist to every window
    set winmatchlist to {}
    set tabmatchlist to {}
    set tabnamematchlist to {}
    repeat with win in winlist
        set ok to true
        try
            set tablist to every tab of win
        on error errmsg
            --display dialog name of win as string
            set ok to false
        end try
        if ok then
            repeat with t in tablist
                if searchpat is in (name of t as string) then
                    set end of winmatchlist to win
                    set end of tabmatchlist to t
                    set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & (index of t as string) & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                    --display dialog name of t as string
                else if searchpat is in (URL of t as string) then
                    set end of winmatchlist to win
                    set end of tabmatchlist to t
                    set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & (index of t as string) & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                    --display dialog name of t as string
                end if
            end repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    if (count of tabmatchlist) = 1 then
        --display dialog "one!"
        set w to item 1 of winmatchlist
        set t to item 1 of tabmatchlist
        set current tab of w to t
        set index of w to 1
    else if (count of tabmatchlist) = 0 then
        if not (exists current tab of front window) then make new document -- if no window
        tell front window    
                  set current tab to (make new tab at end of tabs with properties {URL:theUrl})
      end tell


    else
        set whichtab to choose from list of tabnamematchlist with prompt "The following tabs match, please select one:"
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
        if whichtab is not equal to false then
            set tmp to text items of (whichtab as string)
            set w to (item 1 of tmp) as integer
            set t to (item 2 of tmp) as integer
            set current tab of window id w to tab t of window id w
            set index of window id w to 1
        end if
    end if
end tell
```